# Getting datas from multiple table in one crystal report

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I got 2 tables *tbl_issued* and *tbl_transaction*.

*tbl_issued* has its columns, **ItemID**,**Item**,**Serial**,**Quantity** and **Size**. While *tbl_transaction* has its columns **Released**,**Received**,**Approved** and **Department**

My problem is  I want to get their columns  in 1 query, this is  mysql query

```
SELECT `ItemID`,`Item`,`Serial`,`Quantity`,`Size`,`Class`,`Unit`,(SELECT `Released`  FROM `tbl_transaction` WHERE `TransactionID` = 12458952) AS `Released`,
(SELECT `Received`  FROM `tbl_transaction` WHERE `TransactionID` = 12458952) AS `Received`,
(SELECT `Approved`  FROM `tbl_transaction` WHERE `TransactionID` = 12458952) AS `Aprroved`,
(SELECT `Department`  FROM `tbl_transaction` WHERE `TransactionID` = 12458952) AS `Department`
FROM `tbl_issued` WHERE `TransactionID` =  12458952
```

but transferring this  on vb.net does not provide output.

Any ideas how i will translate this query to vb.net?  Thanks in advance for help!

[image: result from query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_issued WHERE TransactionID = 12458952"]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying to do but if you want it to be simplified, here's how. Have you tried Inner Joins? It's like this.

```
SELECT ItemID, Item, Serial, Quantity, Size, Class, Unit, Released, Received,
Approved, Deparment from tbl_issued a INNER JOIN tbl_transaction b on 
a.TransactionID = b.TransactionID Where a.TransactionID = 12458952
```

I assume that both tables have TransactionID based on your query.

Comment: I'm sorry sir.  are these  "a" corresponds to tbl_issued and "b" corresponds to  tbl_transaction

Comment: yes.. those are what we call Aliases.. it's like what you were doing with your subqueries.. for example: (SELECT Released FROM tbl_transaction WHERE TransactionID = 12458952) AS Released, the "AS" part is where you aliased it as "Released". You can do aliases with or without the "AS". Hope it helped. Kindly mark my answer if it is. Have a nice day!

Comment: It does not display  the value  of my  "Released" field in crystal reports. and  my items  flood all the way down to  my report. maybe  because of  syntax.

Comment: How are you populating your Crystal Report? Directly to database or datatable .NET? I think it would help it you could provide more details on how you are doing it. Regarding the item flood in your report, I think it is because of the inner join. If there are also some links between your two tables aside from your TransactionID, you should join it also.

Comment: this  is my code :  Dim qry As String
            qry = "SELECT ItemID,Item,Serial,Quantity,Size,Class,Unit,Released FROM tbl_issued a INNER JOIN tbl_transaction b ON a.TransactionID = b.TransactionID WHERE a.TransactionID = '" & cBoxIssued.Text & "'"
            Cmd = New MySqlCommand(qry, ConStr)
            SDA.SelectCommand = Cmd
            SDA.Fill(dbDataSet)

Comment: my  link is   from *tbl_issued* **TransactionID* to *tbl_transaction* **TransactionID** that was my  only link.

Comment: I am referring to how you are passing the data from your dataset to the Crystal report you are showing.

Comment: _Report.SetDataSource(dbDataSet) 
            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = _Report
            CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()

Comment: is that what are u referring to?

Comment: Your code seems fine. Regarding the "Released" field you are missing, make sure it is included in Crystal Report. Regarding the flooding, if your link was correct, it should also show records based on your given TransactionID. Try running your query in your database and check the records.

Comment: your code provided  me  exactly what i want . the released field seems okay and  displayed it on CR. but please. help me . why my items flood   in Cr..

Comment: Sir. I found that  my items flood 28x in CR, the same as  my all saved transactions  on tbl_transaction. how to fix that?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot or some data from the item flood? Is it repetitive?

Comment: yes it is repetitive. the same as  all saved transactions on my tbl_transaction. I;m newbie on this forum, and i dont know how to put a screenshot here.

Comment: I've edited my posted code. Try it and let me know the results.

Comment: I tried your new  code, and still same results. and  same floods.

Comment: My guess was the TransactionID is not the only link. Inner Joins gets the matches between the two tables. Plus you have your where "TranscationID = 12458952" part. Do this for testing, run the query in the database itself, run a query for tbl_transaction where TransactionID = 12458952 and also run a query for tbl_issued where TransactionID = 12458952.. compare the results.

Comment: SELECT `ItemID`,`Item`,`Serial`,`Quantity`,`Size`,`Class`,`Unit`,`Released`,`Received`,`Approved`,`Department`,`Purpose` FROM `tbl_issued` INNER JOIN `tbl_transaction` ON `tbl_issued.TransactionID` = `tbl_transaction.TransactionID` WHERE `tbl_issued.TransactionID` = 12458952  is this the same with your code posted earlier?  i tried this  your code. but still no results.

Comment: i dont have primary keys on my 2 tables..  and the  one i said link earlier is the only  link.

Comment: Sir. i provided some  images of my table  and  i create links on my Cr. thanks .  Please see  my  post.

Comment: This is getting kinda long... Provide me these: Screenshot of the RESULT of the query "SELECT * FROM tbl_issued WHERE TransactionID = 12458952", another screenshot for  "SELECT * FROM tbl_transaction WHERE TransactionID = 12458952" and if possible, screenshot of the CR with records...

Comment: Sorry sir, but  thank you very very much...  but one last question .. why did just happen  when  i used the query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_issued WHERE TransactionID = 12458952" it  display  the released, received, department, approved in tbl_transaction . Please see my post. I'd post screenshot of query,

Comment: The result seems fine... Regarding your last question, what do you mean?

Comment: why the  "SELECT * FROM tbl_issued WHERE TransactionID = 12458952" it display the released, received, department, approved in tbl_transaction ?? even  i do not  put it  in my query?  btw.. how to mark  the your answer  ? :D

Comment: Just click the up-arrow near my answer... Glad your problem is solved now. Although I don't know if I made things clear to you.

Comment: ok. maybe  later .. that query will give an error. but  i know that  your posted code will be  my reference to fix this. Thank you sir . even though i'm confused with this .  Hahahaha..  Thanks.!